# jquery, only show if something else is showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way i can check if something doesn't exist, i.e. has not been printed out by PHP, and only then, if it doesn't exist, make the info appear?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#info').hide();
//can i check over here if something with an id of 'space' exists in the document flow, and if it doesn't, then execute the next line?
$('#info').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an element exists you can use the following

```
if ($('#elementID').length) {
   ...
}
```

To check if something doesn't exist you can do

```
if ($('#elementID').length == 0) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (!$('#elementID').length) {
   ...
}
```

So in your case you can do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#info').hide();
    if ($('#space').length == 0) {
        $('#info').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can even be reduced to `if($('#elementID').length){` … `}` for what I know.

Comment: @Xufox Yes because if it returns more that 1, it will be "true".

Comment: `if ($('#space').length == 0)` would be more conventional.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !$('#space') ){
  $('#info').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
}
```

Keeping it simple. You don't need the .length.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use it through php, for example:

```
<?php if(CONDITION): ?>
Content to display
<?php endif; ?>
```

and in particular it could become

```
<?php if($something != "" || Other conditions): ?>
content to display
<?php endif; ?>
```